# Hex-encoded String to Byte Array

Tags: java, string, arrays

```
String str = "9B7D2C34A366BF890C730641E6CECF6F";
```

I want to convert `str` into byte array, but `str.getBytes()` returns 32 bytes instead of 16.

Comment: That's not a bug at all.

Comment: Some valid java code would be helpful...

Comment: @JB Nizet - pretty sure, that the String has 16 characters, each and everyone encoded 16 bit. Which results in - still not really surprising - 32 bytes. Java uses UTF16 internally, 1 char = 2 bytes.

Comment: @Andreas_D: Look at the question of the OP. The STring has 32 characters. Moreover String.getBytes() doesn't return the internal representation of the String as bytes. It returns the String as a byte array, using the default platform encoding (which might be UTF8, ISO8859-1, CP-1252, ..., using 1 byte per ASCII char)

Comment: @JB Nizet - the question does not include valid Java code and it is *my* interpretation that the *stringy thing* is a 16 byte integer value in hex format. (that's why I recommended *valid java code* in my first comment)

Comment: OK. Understood. Without a correct question, hard to give a correct answer.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I think what the questioner is after is converting the string representation of a hexadecimal value to a byte array representing that hexadecimal value.

The apache commons-codec has a class for that, [Hex](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/apidocs/org/apache/commons/codec/binary/Hex.html).

```
String s = "9B7D2C34A366BF890C730641E6CECF6F";    
byte[] bytes = Hex.decodeHex(s.toCharArray());
```

Comment: There is also `org.bouncycastle.util.encoders.Hex` to do that kind of job.

Comment: consider you would have to 'roll your own'. What would then be an example approach?

Answer (score 38):

Java SE 6 or Java EE 5 provides a method to do this now so there is no need for extra libraries.

The method is [DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseHexBinary%28java.lang.String%29)

In this case it can be used as follows:

```
String str = "9B7D2C34A366BF890C730641E6CECF6F";
byte[] bytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(str);
```

The class also provides type conversions for many other formats that are generally used in XML.

Comment: The simplest solution for this question that I came across so far - thanks!

Comment: This should have been the accepted answer since it's the simplest solution that utilises only the core Java libraries.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
str.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
```

Comment: It gives output like  [B@405e898,  but I want the same Str String as Byte Array.

Comment: @Qaiser Mehmood Becuase it's an array so you cannot just print it, you have to make a simple loop to print its elements one by one

Comment: Something like: `for(byte b : str.getBytes("UTF-16LE")) System.out.println(b);`

Comment: That won't convert a hex string to the corresponding bytes. That will convert any string to its UTF16 encoding. By the way, with OP's example string, it will spit out 64 bytes, which is totally not what was requested.

Answer (score 2):

I know it's late but hope it will help someone else...

This is my code: It takes two by two hex representations contained in String and add those into byte array.
It works perfectly for me.

```
public byte[] stringToByteArray (String s) {
    byte[] byteArray = new byte[s.length()/2];
    String[] strBytes = new String[s.length()/2];
    int k = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i=i+2) {
        int j = i+2;
        strBytes[k] = s.substring(i,j);
        byteArray[k] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(strBytes[k], 16);
        k++;
    }
    return byteArray;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do the trick :

```
byte[] bytes = toByteArray(Str.toCharArray());

public static byte[] toByteArray(char[] array) {
    return toByteArray(array, Charset.defaultCharset());
}

public static byte[] toByteArray(char[] array, Charset charset) {
    CharBuffer cbuf = CharBuffer.wrap(array);
    ByteBuffer bbuf = charset.encode(cbuf);
    return bbuf.array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
     String str = "9B7D2C34A366BF890C730641E6CECF6F";
     String[] temp = str.split(",");
     bytesArray = new byte[temp.length];
     int index = 0;
     for (String item: temp) {
     bytesArray[index] = Byte.parseByte(item);
     index++;
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you need is to convert a hex string into a byte array that equals that means the same thing as that hex string?
Adding this method should do it for you, without any extra library importing:

```
public static byte[] hexToByteArray(String s) {
     String[] strBytes = s.split("(?<=\\G.{2})");
     byte[] bytes = new byte[strBytes.length];
     for(int i = 0; i < strBytes.length; i++)
         bytes[i] = (byte)Integer.parseInt(strBytes[i], 16);
     return bytes;
}
```