# Convert string to hex

Tags: java, string, char, hex, byte

I have to update the date and time of a time clock in a dynamic way. I am not able to convert a string to a format accepted by the variable char (not char array).

Is there another way?

Thus that's there works! But not so dynamic ...

```
char year = 0x0E;
char month = 0x0A;
char day = 0x0A;
char hour = 0x0A;
char min = 0x0A;
char sec = 0x0A;

byte[] date_hour = new byte[]{(byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0B, 
                   (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x07, 
                   (byte) year, (byte) month, (byte) day, (byte) hour, (byte) min, (byte) sec, 
                   (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x17};

out.write(date_hour);
```

I wanted something like:

```
public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

//gets...

char year = getYear();
char month = getMont();
char day = getDay();
char hour = getHour();
char min = getMin();
char sec = getSec();

byte[] date_hour = new byte[]{(byte) 0xFE, (byte) 0x82, (byte) 0x71, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x0B, 
                   (byte) 0x01, (byte) 0x00, (byte) 0x07, 
                   (byte) year, (byte) month, (byte) day, (byte) hour, (byte) min, (byte) sec, 
                   (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x17, (byte) 0x0E, (byte) 0x0A, (byte) 0x17};

out.write(date_hour);
```

I tried: 
[Hex-encoded String to Byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650650/hex-encoded-string-to-byte-array)
[How to convert/parse from String to char in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7853502/how-to-convert-parse-from-string-to-char-in-java)

Sorry for my bad english ...
Thanks!

Comment: The char values you need have no relationship to the characters in a string.  Rather, they are numeric values stored in a `char` (which is simply a small integer).  (In fact, you should probably not use `char` at all, but should declare your values as `byte`.)

Comment: Yes, an hour value is not a char - start by using appropriate data types. Joda time has some good classes and Java8 has a decent date/time package.

Comment: I don't get the problem... What are you really trying to do? What is `out.write`? Why do you have a byte array?

Comment: I did making it! Thank you `int year = Integer.parseInt("0E",16);`  

`byte[] date_hour = new byte[]{(byte)((year)&0xff)};
`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert String to char, you can do this:

Suppose **str** is the variable name of string.

```
char ch = str.toCharArray()[0];
```

or, You can use:

```
char ch = str.charAt(0);
```

Both of these will store the first character (which will be the only character in case the String is truly a character) of the String **str** int the Character **ch**.